# How to remove google ad block background color

Tags: adsense, google-ads-api

How to remove goole ad background color...Here take a look [ad image](http://screencloud.net/v/B7oO)...can some one tell me how to remove that background color.....

Ad height and width is:

```
        google_ad_width = 970;
        google_ad_height = 90;
```

Comment: You can only configure ads displayed using Google AdSense UI. You are not allowed to change the code generated as per terms and conditions state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change background color of the adsense block during generation of the ad-unit code from google.com/adsense. Later when you insert adsense code in html tag it only include ad-sense-unit ID. You can (pseudo) remove the background color by making its background color as that of your site background color at time of generating code for new adsense unit code.